# Blackberry cultivar recommendation for west Essex, UK

Tags: soft-fruit

Can anyone recommend a blackberry cultivar that's thornless, vigorous, bears plentiful flavoursome fruit and is suitable for cultivation in west Essex, UK? I'm currently growing "Black Satin", which ticks all those boxes. But is there anything better?

Comment: Good experience here with Stark Bro's fruit. They have 1-2 thornless.